# Sizing wire (calculating ampacity) for solar PV arrays

Tags: solar-panels, solar

I have a solar photovoltaic array consisting of 9 PV modules interconnected in 3s-3p. They are the Jinko Solar JKM450M-60HL4-V panels. I want to know which size of wire I need to choose for the common/main positive and negative wires of the 3 parallel strings. Here's the nameplate:

[image: Nameplate]

Now, according to article 690.8(B), the ampacity of such wires must be greater than or equal to the greater value calculated in 690.8(B)(1) or (B)(2). Let's ignore (B)(2) for simplicity. Now, (B)(1) says:

> **(1) Without Adjustment and Correction Factors.** The maximum currents calculated in 690.8(A) multiplied by 125 percent without adjustment or correction factors.

So, I must first calculate the maximum current in 690.8(A). Such article says I can use (A)(1) or (A)(2); let's use (A)(1). Article (A)(1) is divided into 5 more, depending on which part of the PV system you want to size the wires; in my case, it's the "PV Source Circuit", as defined in 690.2:

> **PV Source Circuit**. The de circuit conductors between modules and from modules to dc combiners, electronic power converters, or a dc PV
> system disconnecting means.
>
> **PV System DC Circuit**. Any de conductor in PV source circuits, PV output circuits, dc-to-dc converter source circuits, and dc-to-dc
> converter output circuits.

[image: Informational Note Figure 690.1(a)]

*Informational Note Figure 690.1(a) Identification of PV Power Source Components.*

Because I want to size the wires in the "PV source circuit", I must use article 690.8(A)(1)(a), which is then subdivided into (A)(1)(a)(1) and (A)(1)(a)(2); in my case I must use (A)(1)(a)(1). Here's a quote:

> (a) *Photovoltaic Source Circuit Currents* The maximum current shall
> be as calculated in either of the following:
>
> (1) The maximum current shall be the sum of the short-circuit current
> ratings of the PV modules connected in parallel multiplied by 125
> percent.
>
> (2) For PV systems with an inverter generating capacity of 100 kW or
> greater, a documented and stamped PV system design, using an industry
> standard method maximum current calculation provided by a licensed
> professional electrical engineer, shall be permitted. The calculated
> [...]

So, as you can see, art. 690.8(A)(1)(a)(1) specifies to calculate the maximum PV source circuit current by summing the short-circuit current rating of the solar panels connected in parallel, and then **multiplying that by 1.25**, but after that art. 690.8(B)(1) says to use the maximum current **multiplied by 1.25**. My question is, **should I multiply twice by 1.25 or just once?**

The maximum current for my solar array would be [(13.85 A/module) × (3 modules)] × (1.25) = [41.55 A] × (1.25) ≈ 51.94 A. What I don't know is if I shall use this as the minimum ampacity for the wires, or if it should be 51.94 A × 1.25 ≈ 64.92 A.

Comment: the first calc is for panel to panel wires. Thus 13.85*1.25.  Than the sum of all 3 panels is also multiple by 1.25 for the outgoing cable

Comment: Will this be on a roof?  Your system voltage will be 123V open circuit which requires **Rapid Shutdown** if you are in a jurisdiction which protects firemen on roofs.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica Yep. But I think that is a bit irrelevant for the question. Thank you anyways!

Comment: No it isn't. You can't just ignore Rapid Shutdown and then slap it on as an afterthought.  Well, you can, if cost is no object... but you'll have forehead-slap moments like "gosh wow, *if I'd only known this*, I could have done this so much easier!"